# why git revert command, reverts the commit from end of the specific path not start of it?

Tags: git

I wanted to revert bunch of commits, and I realized the commits get reverted from the end of the range to the start, so I was wondering why it doesn't revert from starting commit of the range to the ending commit?

the reason revert gets used is to undo some of the buggy commits, so when the commits get reverted from the end and since commits get reverted based on their previous commit, so if their previous commit be buggy, you maybe undo the bugs of the specific commit but because the process of reverting of that commit depends on its previous commit and previous commit is buggy, so the bugs of that previous commits will remain in the resulting reverted commit.

but if you revert from start of the commits range because the previous commit is a clean commit, you will remove all the bugs and you don't have any bugs in the resulting commits.

so I want to know why commits in a range get reverted from the end and is my logic correct or not? and is there any approach to revert from starting commit to ending commit?

command:

```
git revert 678gf45~1..b9d9a21 (head is currently pointing to test branch)
```

Diagrams:

Current history:

```
*   b9d9a21 (master) Merge
|\
| * 0542684 G
* | 7474ecd F
|/
* 4d49fcc E
|
| * bdad508 (HEAD -> test) D 
| * a884ffa C
| * 5673a97 B
|/
*678gf45 A
```

History after revert:

```
* da715de (HEAD -> test) Revert "E"
* f693893 Revert "F"
* a890f49 Revert "G"
* d4c1210 Revert "Merge"
* bdad508 D
* a884ffa C
* 5673a97 B
| *   b9d9a21 (master) Merge
| |\
| | * 0542684 G
| * | 7474ecd F
| |/
| * 4d49fcc E
|/
*678gf45 A
```

Expected history after revert:

```
* d4c1210 (HEAD -> test) Revert "Merge"
* a890f49 Revert "G"
* f693893 Revert "F"
* da715de Revert "E"
* bdad508 D
* a884ffa C
* 5673a97 B
| *   b9d9a21 (master) Merge
| |\
| | * 0542684 G
| * | 7474ecd F
| |/
| * 4d49fcc E
|/
*678gf45 A
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that commits are reverted in reverse order is that it is the order in which the reversal will be possible without generating unnecessary conflicts.

In the following, I'm focusing on this part of the history:

```
* 7474ecd F
* 4d49fcc E
* 678gf45 A
```

I am omitting commit `G` because it occurs in a branchy history and complicates matters unnecessarily, and it is not necessary to highlight my point. The command considered is now `git revert 678gf45~1..7474ecd`.

Let's say, there is a file `foo.txt` in the project.

- In commit `A`, it has the content `I am A`.
- In commit `E`, it has the content `I am E`.
- In commit `F`, it has the content `I am F`.

The instruction that `git revert` follows are (transliterated, the real operation behind the scenes is a content merge operation) the opposite of the content change that each commit introduced. So, they are:

- "To revert commit `F`, change content `I am F` to `I am E`."
- "To revert commit `E`, change content `I am E` to `I am A`."

These "instructions" are always the same regardless of the current state of the file `foo.txt`.

What happens if we start with the reversal of `F`? The current contents of the file is that at `F` and is `I am F`. The instruction is "change `I am F` to `I am E`". It is trivial to follow this instruction. We end up with a commit where the state of `foo.txt` is `I am E`.

Now let's see what happens if we start with the reversal of `E` instead. The instruction is to "change `I am E` to `I am A`". The current state of the file is, however, `I am F`. So, ... what shall we do? There is no `I am E` anywhere (remember, we have `I am F`). How could we turn it into `I am A`? We cannot! This is a classic content conflict, where we have to ask the user for help.

This difference which kinds of changes can be done automatically is the reason that reversals occur in the reverse order.

Comment: @ j6t I have a logic which I post it as an answer below due to lack of space in comment section, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

don't you think these conflicts are necessary?

for instance in your scenario, lets consider `foo.txt` a clean and bugless file, when we start to revert from end of the range, the `I am F` which we have in the last commit gets reverts to `I am A` in the last resulting commits from reverting process, which this revert is unnecessary for this file.

but in another scenario if we revert from the beginning we **can keep** `I am F` in the last resulting commit from reverting process, in the other words, at start of the revert we **can have**`I am E` and in the last commit from revert process we have `I am F` and just by that we managed to keep a clean file out of getting reverted for no reason.

the reason I bolded **can keep** and **can have**, is because for **keeping** and **having** those values you should resolve a conflict, so it is up to user to choose what they want but in your scenario there is no option and even the clean files get reverted.

another problem I have is, lets consider `foo.txt` as a buggy file, so in your scenario when we revert the commits from the end, in the first resulting commit
we have `I am E`, then we have `I am A`.

so if we consider `I am F` and `I am E` as bugs in this specific file and as a bug we want them to get fixed as soon as possible but in your scenario first we have `I am E` which is a buggy chunk of code or text then `I am A` which is a clean chunk of code or text.

but in my scenario, we can have `I am A` from the first resulting commit till the last one but we have to resolve conflicts.

and for a buggy file in your scenario, the bug is getting mitigated then fixed, but in my scenario the bug can be fixed from the start.

that's the reason I think those conflicts are necessary and revert should start from the first commit and not the last commit of the range.

so what do you think about this logic? @j6t

Comment: Do I understand correctly: In your first scenario, `I am F` is correct, then you do the reverting, and then in the end you still want `I am F`, because it is the correct text after all? In your second scenario, `I am F` is bogus and the correct state is `I am A`, and to arrive at this corrected state you are using `git revert`?

Comment: yeah that's right @j6t

Comment: In the second scenario, you have to decide whether `git revert` is really the right tool. It is, if all changes (not just that of `foo.txt`) must be undone. A secondary decision is whether it is warranted to undo the changes in stages and whether the temporarily bogus `foo.txt` hurts, or if a single wholesale-undo is better. It is more a matter of what you want the history to look like, not so much of whether intermediate states are free of bugs. `git revert` is the wrong tool if there are only part of the changes must be undone.

Comment: In the first scenario, using `git revert` sounds like the wrong tool to use if `foo.txt` is a central part of the changes. However, if the changes in `foo.txt` are just collateral (such as an unrelated documentation that was fixed up on the way), then `git revert` is warranted, but still the order must be reverse due to the changes to the *other* files (and then it is also warranted to back out the reversals in `foo.txt` to keep its state correct and unmodified). Nothing of this is an argument that the reverts should be in the original order.

Comment: so what tool you recommend? @j6t

Comment: I cannot tell because you didn't say what you need a tool for. Please ask a new question. Do not forget to show what you have tried, what your desired result is and in which form your tries did not give the desired results.

Comment: ok,tnx for your responses...@j6t